# How to output new line when using Formatter.format?

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

public class createfile {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        createfile obj= new createfile();
        obj.openfile();
        obj.addRecords();
        obj.closefile();
        System.out.println("You have created a file");

    }
    private Formatter x;
    public void openfile(){

        try{
            x = new Formatter("C:\\test\\chinese.txt");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("You have an error");
        }
    }




    public void `addRecords`(){
        x.format("%s %s %s","21","alex","software programmer");
        x.format("%s %s %s","22","greg", "architecture");
    }
    public void closefile(){
        x.close();
    }
}
```

In this program i have everything running perfectly but in the addRecord() function i need to add more information but i am not able to print it on a new line.Everything is displaying in the same line.Can someone point me out on that
Thank You..

Comment: Try to use `%n' in format or `\n` in line for new line.

Comment: @bmthaker: `\n` is frowned upon inside of a Formatter. You should use `%n` only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `%n` format specifier to add a new line via `Formatter#format(...)`. So add this to the end of your format String.

Comment: can u explain in detail..with an appropriate example..i have tried the above mentioned method...may be i am messing up with something..please can u show me with a short and simple example.

Comment: @ChaoAbhishekPhukan: oh for the love of Pete, just put `%n` at the end of your format String in your `format(...)` call. Come on now, surely you can try to do this.

Comment: ok ok i have the output now..hehe...thanx a ton

Comment: keep helping...we are learners...